# Route group laravel

Tags: laravel, route

Как мне правильно использовать Route::group?
У меня есть код:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    'middleware' => 'admin',
    'namespace' => 'Admin',
], function () {
    Route::get('',  function () {
        return ('Hello World');
    });
});
```

Но страница admin/ не найдена.Почему?При этом маршрут есть в `php artisan route:list`.Также если данный код `Route::get('admin/',  function () {
        return ('Hello World');
    });` работает, если бы я использовал его вне группы.В чем же дело?

Comment: А `get('',  ...` ни на какие мысли не наводит?..

Comment: @IgorDyshlenko, точно также не работает и '/'

Comment: покажи весь файл маршрутов